# Image and separator positioning

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have a problem in my weather webapp.

As you can see on the screenshot below, if the width of the device is low, the forecast is displayed correctly, but if you browse the page on a desktop or on an ipad, the images don't stay on the left.

High width screen

[image]

Small width screen

[image]

This is the code of one single day:

```
echo '<div class="line-separator"></div>';
echo '<img class="small_img_meteo" src="images/' .$img1 . '.png"/>';
echo '<p>'.$name1.'<br />' .$condizione_txt1. '</p>';
echo '&nbsp';
```

And here is the stylesheet

```
.small_img_meteo{
position:relative;
float:left;
width:20%;
}

.line-separator{

height:1px;

background:#FFFFFF;

border-bottom:1px solid #717171;

}
```

Unfortunately, **I can't use vw size** for the fonts

So, is there a way to put the line-separator just at the end of the image ( because they actually overlay the images, and they just care about the end of the text), or else to fix the images to the left

Comment: provide us a example of data

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice.  Have you tried using a border at the bottom of each image ala border-bottom?

Comment: did you clear your floating elements??

Comment: Considering this is tabular data, is there a reason why you're *not* using a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your images float.
Add a `clear: both;` to `.line-separator`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution:

```
.line-separator {
    clear: both;
    height:1px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #717171;
}
```

The problem is that all the images have a float. That causes the text to set the height. By clearing the floats, this problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks Guys! Both solutions were correct but the other guy typed it 20 sec earlier:D

Comment: Can't argue that logic.

Comment: I accepted his answer as correct, even if yours was also right, because he typed it faster.